# JTable-condition if((table.getValueAt(0, 1)).equals("")) shows error

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, jtable, jbutton

I made empty table:

```
String columnNames[] = {"br", "artikal", "cena", "kolicina","ukupno" };  
String dataValues[][] =new String[10][5];  
DefaultTableModel tableModel=new DefaultTableModel(dataValues, columnNames);
```

and I want to fill one column by order from first row to last by loop and if condition:

```
if ((((JButton)e.getSource()).getText()).equals(name.getName())){

    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){

        String products= (String) bill.tableModel.getValueAt(i, 1);
        String p=Double.toString(name.getPrice());

        if(products.equals(""))                                                                                                  
            bill.tableModel.setValueAt(name.getName(),i, 1);
            bill.tableModel.setValueAt(p,i, 2);
            break;   
    }
}
```

When I click button, shows nothing, but when I delete if condition `if (products.equals(""))`  it's working, but instead to fill cell in column which is empty, it set text to first cell in column all over again.

I  tried  `if ( dataValues[i][1].equals("null"))` and `if (products.equals("null"))` it showes nothing.
When I put `System.out.print((String) bill.tableModel.getValueAt(0, 1))` shows "null" on console.

Is there other way to fill cells in column?

Comment: If `products` is `null` it would throw a NPE when you tried to use it.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: `if ((((JButton)e.getSource()).getText()).equals(name.getName())){` is a rather strange way to implement action listeners logic...

Comment: Exactly. SO ... check for `null` if that's an expected condition. `if (products == null)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should probably be:

```
if(products!=null && products.equals("")) {
    bill.tableModel.setValueAt(name.getName(),i, 1);
    bill.tableModel.setValueAt(p,i, 2);
}
```

I am assuming the curly braces around the if statement's body since I do not quire understand what you are trying to do when the button is clicked....

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
 if (e.getSource()instanceof JButton){

                  for (Product name:Main.manu){


                        if ((((JButton)e.getSource()).getText()).equals(name.getName())){


                            for (int i=0;i<10;i++){

                                String products= (String) bill.tableModel.getValueAt(i, 1);
                                String p=Double.toString(name.getPrice());

                                if (products!=null)  
                                continue;
                                {                                                                                                

                                    bill.tableModel.setValueAt(name.getName(),i, 1);
                                    bill.tableModel.setValueAt(p,i, 2);


                                break;   }


                        }

                      }
                 }                
                }
            }
```